# Better way of protecting VBA than Excel built-in?

Tags: excel

I have noted that password protection on XLSM files is easily broken, exposing all VBA code.

What alternative methods exist that offer more security than simply adding password protection on the project settings?

Comment: Not much if you are going to share the workbook. It is easily bypassed with brute force.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone interested in truly protecting their VBA projects check out the following step by step guide(Collected and Tested). I found it working fine for me.

```
1. Open your desired file.
2. Press Alt+F11 to access the add-in's vba project
3. Lock the vba-project with a password
4. Double-click on the "ThisWorkbook" code module
5. Press F4 to open the Properties window
6. Change the "IsAddin" status to FALSE
7. Return to Excel by Pressing Alt+Q (or close the vbe window)
8. Go to Review TAB > Share Workbook
9. When the dialogue appears, check the box for: (Allow changes by.....)
10. Press OK to close the Dialogue
11. When prompted to save, Press OK
12. Press Ok to accept that "macros cannot be accessed"
13. You should feel giddy at this point because you just realized what you havebeen missing right under your nose
14. Verify that the [SHARED] appears in the application title bar
15. Now save the workbook again.
16. Close this Excel workbook.
17. Test out your newly saved file (open it, access the vba, try to expand the project window, you should get the new message "Project is Unviewable"
18. Your done
```

Comment: Thank you for the response, but it seems that there are many VBA methods that cannot be used when the workbook is shared.

Comment: Do you mean a single worksheet? I am trying to lock a workbook, and unfortunately I receive an error when trying to run the macros.

Comment: No, I mean a workbook. Just it will prompt `Project is unviewable` when you try to expand vba window. But it will cause no hamper to your macros.

Answer (score 0):

**Making your VBA project unviewable**

make a copy of the Excel file you want to make unviewable (remember – once you do it there is no way back!) and change it’s extension to .zip. Right-click on the archive and go to Open with > WinRAR
double-click on xl folder and extract vbaProject.bin file or drag & drop the file onto your Desktop. Once you have it extracted, right-click on the file, Open with Notepad++.

For Excel workbook files (tested on .xlsb) you can replace the CMG, DPB and GC strings between parenthesis with any even number of “F”s greater than or equal to the number of characters in the original strings and for Add-in files (tested on .xlam) you need to replace them with the exact same number of “F”s as the number of characters in the original strings.

Save the changes close Notepad++ and drag & drop the file back in the archive to replace the original with the updated one.

change the extension from .zip back to original Excel file extension (.xlsb, .xlam, etc.). Now when you open the file, go to VB Editor and try to expand the VBA project. Instead of password prompt you should see a message saying that the Project is unviewable.

*You project is now uncrackable. No one (even you) can see or edit the VBA code.*